# How to set a hidden style to a spring:message tag

Tags: css

I am using the spring:message tag to basically display a label over an input field.

Example:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <spring:message code="referral.common.dateInterview"/><br>  
        <myui:calendar title="Max Date of Interview" path="maxDateInterview" bootstrapped="true" placeholder="${messages['common.uTo']}" inputCssClass="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Which renders like this:

[image]

I want the message code to remain in the code, but hidden to the user like when you set any label to `style="display:none"`.  I don't know how to set this attribute on a spring message tag.

Is there a way to hide a spring message to the user?  I don't want the user to see the label "Date of Interview" above the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Spring's `message` tag doesn't provide attribute you need. All it does is rendering text retrieved from message bundle. If you want to hide it by `display:none` you should wrap it in some HTML tag and apply hiding style on this outer tag.

It could look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="hidden">
        <spring:message code="referral.common.dateInterview"/>
    </div>
    <myui:calendar title="Max Date of Interview" path="maxDateInterview" bootstrapped="true" placeholder="${messages['common.uTo']}" inputCssClass="form-control" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```